# Where to keep holy books

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, holy-objects

I understand that holy books may not be kept in a bedroom. May one keep holy books in the kitchen or in the bedroom in a closed cupboard if a dwelling is a studio and does not have a separate living room?

Comment: I believe the Avnei Yasfei holds that a closet door is considered a mechitzah,also seforim can be in a bedroom as long as they are put away or covered halachichly correct during relations

Comment: Where did you hear this, and was there some defining characteristic of the bedroom that was mentioned (a room with a bed, a room with a couch upon which someone sleeps occasionally, frequently, regularly, room in an abandoned warehouse in which someone retreats for some quiet rest but likes to learn on his way to/from and so carries said book...)?